# How to fix this error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset

Tags: git, github, substrate

I ran the following command, but this message has displayed.
How can I fix it?

```
E:\Workspace\Blockchain>git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
Cloning into 'substrate-node-template'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2185, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
error: 2269 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Please, help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your internet connection reliable?

Comment: I was having this problem consistently with Visual Studio Enterprise but when I opened the same directory with vscode it was able to push my changes without issue. Could have been coincidence, but worth a try.

Answer (score 15):

- Set http.version to HTTP/1.1 and then perform git push.
- Revert back to HTTP/2 later.

  git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1

  git config --global http.version HTTP/2

Comment: This worked for me too, but do you have any more info on this? like why the push wasn't compatible with HTTP/2?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the git buffer size to hundreds of terabytes did not solve this for me, the problem is that server or your connection does not allow reliable download of data, in my case increasing the request size and timeout limit on my server (IIS) solved the problem.

One sign to watch for is that at first it might fail at 7% for example, as you increase the request size or timeout it will now fail at 33%, just increase the limits further to fix the problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only this repository cloning failed at about 94% always.
How can I increase my request size?

Comment: If you succeed even just 1 time, the problem is not the size limit but timeout might still be responsible, how to configure it is for another question and dependent on your webserver.The problem might be incorrect network config like MTU at your or servers side so keep digging